2D-FDM of heat exchanger
I am an undergraduate student majoring in Mechanical Engineering.
I am currently attempting to compare the e-NTU method and the Energy Balance Equation for a 2D-Laminar counter flow heat exchanger. Although the results from the FDM (Finite Difference Method) are converging, they significantly differ from the values presented in the paper (Table 2), showing about 0.1 lower values.
Could anyone experienced in this field help me with this issue? Thank you.
Codes below is what I've done to calculate effectiveness.
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# Set up matrix
for m_0, k in [(1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (2,0.5), (2,1), (2,2)]:

    # mesh generation
    y1, y2, xi_L = 1, 1, 1
    del_y1, del_y2, del_z = 10**(-1.5), 10**(-1.5), 10**(-4)  
    m, n1, n2 = int((xi_L/del_z)+1), int((y1/del_y1)+1), int((y2/del_y2)+1)

    # Use GPU if available
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    # theta_n1, theta_n2, theta_w initialization with boundary conditions
    theta_n1 =  torch.zeros((m, n1), device=device)
    theta_n2 = torch.zeros((m, n2), device=device)
    theta_w = torch.zeros((m, 1), device=device)
    theta_n1[0, :] = 0  # Inlet n1
    theta_n2[m-1, :] = 1  # Inlet n2
    theta_w[0] = 0  # Wall at zeta = 0
    theta_w[m-1] = 1  # Wall at zeta = 1
    theta_n1[m-1, n1-1] = 1  # Outlet n1
    theta_n2[0, n2-1] = 0  # Outlet n2

    # Tolerance
    errormax = 1e-5
    error = 1
    errors = []
    iteration = 0

    def update(theta_n1, theta_n2, theta_w):

        # Update boundary conditions
        theta_w[1:-1, 0] = (k/(1+k)) * theta_n2[1:-1, n2-2] + (1/(1+k)) * theta_n1[1:-1, n1-2]
        theta_n1[:, n1-1] = theta_w[:, 0]
        theta_n2[:, n2-1] = theta_w[:, 0]
        theta_n1[:, 0] = theta_n1[:, 1]
        theta_n2[:, 0] = theta_n2[:, 1]
        
        # Update inner points
        a1 = del_y1 * del_y1
        b1 = 0.75 * (1 - (torch.arange(1, n1-1, device=device) * del_y1) ** 2)
        c1 = del_z

        a2 = del_y2 * del_y2
        b2 = -0.75 * m_0 * (1 - (torch.arange(1, n2-1, device=device) * del_y2) ** 2)
        c2 = del_z

        # Update theta_n1
        theta_n1[1:m, 1:n1-1] = (c1 / (2 * a1 * b1)) * (theta_n1[:m-1, 2:n1] + theta_n1[:m-1, :n1-2]) + \
                                (1 - (c1 / (a1 * b1))) * theta_n1[:m-1, 1:n1-1]
        # Update theta_n2
        theta_n2[:m-1, 1:n2-1] = -(c2 / (2 * a2 * b2)) * (theta_n2[1:m, 2:n2] + theta_n2[1:m, :n2-2]) + \
                                (1 + (c2 / (a2 * b2))) * theta_n2[1:m, 1:n2-1]

        theta_w[1:-1, 0] = (k/(1+k)) * theta_n2[1:-1, n2-2] + (1/(1+k)) * theta_n1[1:-1, n1-2]
        theta_n1[:, n1-1] = theta_w[:, 0]
        theta_n2[:, n2-1] = theta_w[:, 0]
        theta_n1[:, 0] = theta_n1[:, 1]
        theta_n2[:, 0] = theta_n2[:, 1]

        return theta_n1, theta_n2, theta_w

    tic = datetime.now()

    while error > errormax:
        theta_n1_old = theta_n1.clone()
        theta_n2_old = theta_n2.clone()
        theta_w_old = theta_w.clone()
        
        theta_n1, theta_n2, theta_w = update(theta_n1, theta_n2, theta_w)
        
        error1 = torch.max(torch.abs(theta_n1 - theta_n1_old))  
        error2 = torch.max(torch.abs(theta_n2 - theta_n2_old))
        error = torch.max(error1, error2)
        errors.append(error.item())
        iteration += 1
        if iteration % 2500 == 0:
            toc = datetime.now()
            print(f"Iteration: {iteration}, Error: {error}, consumed_time: {toc - tic}")    


    # Save the results
    xi = torch.linspace(0, xi_L, m).cpu().numpy()
    y1_values = torch.linspace(0, y1, n1).cpu().numpy()
    y2_values = torch.linspace(0, y2, n2).cpu().numpy()

    T_n1 = theta_n1.cpu().numpy()
    T_n2 = theta_n2.cpu().numpy()

    # np.mean(T_n1[-1]) should be same with effectivness
    print(f'mean(m,k): ({m_0}, {k}) : {np.mean(T_n1[-1])}')

Table below is what I get from this code. It should be same, but there are some discrepancy between these two. I think e-NTU method fits well with papers I've read, so problems may lie in the code.


Vera, M., & Linan, A. (2010). Laminar counterflow parallel-plate heat exchangers: exact and approximate solutions. International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer, 53(21-22), 4885-4898.


It's always possible this iteration converges extremely slowly. Try dropping your error by a few orders of magnitude and see if the results change. If it's not that, the next thing I'd check is a finer grid spacing (decrease your del_ variables). If they still don't change, you'll need to triple-check your equations
